# Differential characterization of affine space

Tags: differential-geometry

I am trying to deduce the affine structure of Minkowski spacetime from its metric.

More precisely, let $M$ a smooth manifold and $\nabla$ an affine connection of $M$ such as its torsion and curvature are zero, and for all $p\in M$, $\exp_p$ is defined on all the tangent space $T_p M$ and $\exp_p$ is bijective. Then is $M$ an affine space?

It seems the addition of a point $p\in M$ with a tangent vector $v\in T_p M$ is just $\exp_p(v)$.

Comment: Yes, such a thing is a complete connected (locally)  flat affine manifold and it is known to be isomorphic to the affine space (you do not even need the exponential maps to be diffeomorphisms, simply connected will suffice). A proof should be in one of Kuiper's old papers.

Comment: This is straightforward. Assume manifold is simply connected. Start with any tangent frame at a point. Zero curvature implies you can extend it to a global frame by parallel translation. Zero torsion implies the vector fields comprising the frame commute. Therefore there exist coordinates such that the frame is the coordinate frame. It is easy to check that connection preserving maps are affine with respect to the coordinates.